# ¿Cómo especificar días en los que se ejecutara un evento en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, schedule

Tengo una gran duda acerca de los eventos que se pueden programar con phpmyadmin, lo que intento hacer es eliminar registros de una tabla los días 27 de cada mes.

```sql
CREATE EVENT limpieza
ON SCHEDULE AT now() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO DELETE carrera WHERE carrera = Administracion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intente configurar su evento de la siguiente forma:

```sql
mysql> DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `limpieza`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `limpieza`
    ->   ON SCHEDULE
    ->     EVERY 1 MONTH
    ->     STARTS '2017-01-27 00:00:00'
    ->     DO
    ->       DELETE FROM `carrera`
    ->       WHERE `carrera` = 'Administracion';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si bien la funcionalidad de **EVENTOS** en MySQL ofrece mucha flexibilidad, quizás no tiene toda la potencia expresiva y de opciones de, por ejemplo, **cron** de Unix.

Por ello, una opción para lograr lo que necesita puede ser:

```sql
mysql> DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `limpieza`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `limpieza`
    ->   ON SCHEDULE
    ->     EVERY 1 DAY
    ->     STARTS '2017-01-27 00:00:00'
    ->     COMMENT 'EVENTO ejecutado a diario. DELETE ejecutado primer lunes mes'
    ->     DO
    ->       BEGIN
    ->         IF (DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 AND
    ->             DAYOFWEEK(NOW()) = 2) THEN
    ->           DELETE FROM `carrera`
    ->           WHERE `carrera` = 'Administracion';
    ->         END IF;
    ->       END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, lo probare :) muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Me funciono Muy bien pero digamos que si quiero que se limpie cada primer lunes de cada mes como podria hacer la sentencia? @wchiquito Gracias!

Comment: @KevinDuarte: Ver la actualización en la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @wchiquito Me funciono!

Comment: si además quieren que se ejecute a una hora especifica ese mismo día pueden revisar esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84316/como-ejecutar-la-limpieza-cada-primer-lunes-de-cada-mes/84352#84352).

Comment: @JesseR.Jose: El evento configurado en la respuesta se ejecuta a una hora en específico (`00:00:00`) cada día.

Comment: hooo OK!! yo creía que el `start` solo indicaba a que hora iniciaría a contar el tiempo, del evento. no a que hora exacta se ejecutaría cada día. Por ejemplo si quiero que inicie 3 días después. ok si indico a las `16:00:00` y el evento es `EVERY 1 DAY` el sumara 24 horas al tiempo de `start`.

Comment: @JesseR.Jose: Para una explicación detallada, visitar [13.1.12 CREATE EVENT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear el evento de esta manera para que se ejecute todos los 27 a la 1 de la mañana.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE EVENT STAT
ON  SCHEDULE  EVERY  1  MONTH  STARTS DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE())-1 DAY),INTERVAL 26 DAY),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
ON  COMPLETION  PRESERVE  ENABLE
DO 
BEGIN
DELETE FROM `carrera` WHERE `carrera` = 'Administracion';
CALL STAT();
END;
```