# Como ejecutar la limpieza cada primer lunes de cada mes?

Tags: mysql

Hola Eh estado trabajando con el planificador de eventos de mysql y todo me anda bien con las sentencias pero la verdad no llevo mucho tiempo con esto del planificador se hacer lo básico y e investigo como hacer una función que se ejecute solo el primer lunes de cada mes a las 4:00 pero no logro hacerlo alguien podría orientarme? Gracias!

pequeño ejemplo:

```
mysql> DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `limpieza`;


CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `limpieza`
       ON SCHEDULE
         EVERY 1 MONTH
         STARTS '2017-07-06 16:00.00'
         DO
           DELETE FROM `carrera`
           WHERE `carrera` = 'Administracion';
```

Comment: Ya probe el código y funciona correctamente. Si te ha sido de utilidad puedes marcar lo como mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por alguna razón las condiciones multiples no se ejecutan correctamente, dentro de un evento.

Pero encontré una forma de hacer lo que quieres.

1) Debes crear un `PROCEDURE` y poner las condiciones de tiempo dentro.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `procerure_limpiar`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE procerure_limpiar()
BEGIN   
    SET @fecha := (SELECT fecha FROM nombre_tabla WHERE id_fila = 1);
    SELECT @fecha;    
    IF DATE_FORMAT(@fecha, '%Y %ac %d %H') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y %ac %d %H') 
        THEN DELETE * FROM `carrera` WHERE`carrera` = 'Administracion';
    END IF;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

**Nota:** con el `DATE_FORMAR(NOW(), '%Y %ac %d %H')` estamos retornando `2017-07-07 16` fijate que solo obtengo la hora y no los minutos ni microsegundos. Para evitar fallos en caso de que haya un atraso a la hora que se invoque el PROCEDURE.

2) Crea el `EVENT` y dentro debes invocar el PROCEDURE ya creado.

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `evento_limpiar`;

CREATE EVENT `evento_limpiar` 
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
  STARTS '2017-07-06 16:00.00'
DO
  CALL procerure_limpiar();
```

También Puedes probar el `PROCEDURE` en cualquier momento con solo invocarlo

```
CALL procerure_limpiar();
```

**Nota:** El evento se invoca cada hora pero la sentencia DELETE solo se ejecutara en la fecha y hora establecida.

> Actualización por pate de [@wchiquito](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83119/c%C3%B3mo-especificar-d%C3%ADas-en-los-que-se-ejecutara-un-evento-en-mysql/83155#83155)

De esta forma no hay que almacenar la fecha del evento en la base de datos.

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `limpieza`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `limpieza`
       ON SCHEDULE
         EVERY 1 HOUR
         STARTS '2017-01-27 00:00.00'
         COMMENT 'EVENTO ejecutado a cada hora. DELETE ejecutado primer lunes mes a las 4:00 PM'
         DO
           BEGIN
             IF (DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) BETWEEN 1 AND 7 AND
                 DAYNAME(NOW()) = 'Monday' AND HOUR(NOW()) = 16) THEN
               DELETE FROM `carrera`
               WHERE `carrera` = 'Administracion';
             END IF;
           END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Para mas información pueden ir a su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83119/c%C3%B3mo-especificar-d%C3%ADas-en-los-que-se-ejecutara-un-evento-en-mysql/83155#83155).

**Nota:** si utilizamos `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE` el evento no desaparecerá al ejecutarse. De lo contrario si queremos que desaparezca podemos usar `ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE`.

Espero que esto te haya sido de utilidad.

Comment: Para la hora exacta y el día exacto deberías crear una función que determine que día es el primer lunes de cada mes, y después almacenarlo en la base de datos. así solo tendrás que utilizar un if para el evento.

Comment: ¿Le funciona la creación del evento?. Obtengo el siguiente error al intentar crearlo: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM \`carrera\` WHERE \`carrera\` = 'Administracion' ' at line 10`.

Comment: he agregado mas información a la respuesta, espero haber aclarado las dudas.

Comment: Entiendo que se debería usar un [`IF statement`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) y no un [`IF() function`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

Comment: @wchiquito  Ya he corregido el problema. Puedes probar el código con toda confianza.

Comment: El cambio me funcionó. Aquí otra opción para solventar el problema, [https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/83155/3543](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/83155/3543).

Comment: @wchiquito gracias por la contribución a la respuesta.